# Get element on which keydown happened in contenteditable

Tags: javascript, html, wysiwyg, contenteditable

I have a `div` that is `contenteditable` and that div has some contents:

```
<div contenteditable="true" id="editable-div">
  <p id="paragraph">
    Lorem <em>ipsum</em> dolor sit <strong id="stong-el">amet</strong>
  <p>
</div>
```

I want to intercept `keydown` events and find the element into which the users have tried to write.

I have already failed to find the specific element when listening on the content editable div:

```
const div = document.getElementById('editable-div');
div.addEventListener('keydown', event => { /* ??? */ }, false);
```

Problem: The event in the callback does not tell me which element has been written into, it only tells my I have written in `#editable-div`

My other attempt was to listen on the nested event, like so:

```
// either
const el = document.getElementById('paragraph');

// or
const el = document.getElementById('stong-el');

el.addEventListener('keydown', event => { /* ??? */ }, false);
```

The problem with this is that the event never fires. Apparently the event only fires on the element that has the `contenteditable` attribute, which kind of sucks.

The last resort I have would be to listen on `#editable-div` and check which element has the text selection, but I'd rather not if there is any other way.

**UPDATE**

Another way I found was to use a `MutationObserver` on the editable element, something like this:

```
const observer = new MutationObserver(mutations => {
  mutations.forEach(function(mutation) {
    console.log(mutation.target);
  });
});

const config = { characterData: true, subtree: true };
const div = document.getElementById('editable-div');

observer.observe(div, config);
```

This logs the text element I edited.

I am not sure if my questions is answered with this, because in the end I want to do 2 things:

1. Catch and prevent the event to update an internal data structure
2. Render React components from the data structure

and this does not seem to be an appropriate solution for this.

Comment: Did you find a solution to this? I'm running into the same problem building a plugin for a WYSIWYG editor.

Answer (score 1):

You could check the `focusNode` of the current text selection to get the DOM node in which the keydown event occurred:

```js
const div = document.getElementById('editable-div');
div.addEventListener('keydown', event => {
    console.log(window.getSelection()?.focusNode);
}, false);
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/getSelection

Answer (score 0):

You could attach the keydown event to the body of your document. Then on keydown event, use document.activeElement to return the element which currently has focus and will receive the keyboard input.

Here is a link that explains document.activeElement (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/activeElement)

Comment: Thanks, I just tried it, but this also just gives me the `#editable-div`

Comment: You could store the text values of your elements with ids paragraph and stong-el, let the character be added, check if either of the previous elements text value has changed if so, you know which element got the text, then either reset their text values to the original or do whatever it is you want to do.

Comment: Sounds like too much can go wrong and performance might be bad…

Answer (score 0):

You can put listener on contenteditable element, and then check which element got updated, by comparing its new text with old one. And depending on that you can perform your action in respective branch.

check this codeblock -

```
<div id="ce" contenteditable="true">
    <strong id="s">Abc</strong><br/>
    <i id="i">Hello</i>
</div>

<script>

    oldstext = document.getElementById('s').textContent;
    olditext = document.getElementById('i').textContent;

    document.getElementById('ce').addEventListener('keydown', event => { 
        //alert("ce Edited");
        if(oldstext != document.getElementById('s').textContent){
            console.log(oldstext + "   v/s  " + document.getElementById('s').textContent);
            oldstext = document.getElementById('s').textContent;
        }
        else if (olditext != document.getElementById('i').textContent){
            console.log(olditext + "   v/s  " + document.getElementById('i').textContent);
            olditext = document.getElementById('i').textContent;
        }


    }, false);
</script>
```

Comment: To me this sounds like a solution prone to error and with bad performance, thanks though